# Trying to execute a raw query and getting blank object

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to run a raw query in Django where an user may have phone no like 1234567890,0987654321,6543217890. i need to get all users info with some no's from a table. Trying to execute a raw query in this case but the object that is returning to me is blank. Where as same query in database is able to gather some of rows.

```
Query = "SELECT * FROM  `TableName` WHERE `phonenos` LIKE  '%1234567890%' OR `phonenos` LIKE  '%6543217890%'"
    id = Tablename.objects.raw(Query)
    try:
        print id[0]
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

Comment: you said `not like` but your query use `like`. Show us your db sample data and expected result. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: try to change `SELECT *` to `SELECT phonenos` just to be sure that first column `id[0]` has valid data

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza its phone no like.
Please read the question correctly

Comment: Maybe you write it better? Why are 3 number, but in your query only 2? Still not clear what you want. Show us db sample data and expected result

Comment: at least post your model